# Auto-change IP address in WinCC Professional

Tags: plc, siemens, wincc

I have a project on WinCC professional where Two PLCs (S7-300) are connected to a PC station via Ethernet, one is master and the other one is a Standby.
when a switchover happens, the WinCC must change the ip address so it reads from the standby PLC.
So, How an automatic IP address change could be implemented in WinCC Prof.?
consider changing the IP after an internal HMI tag is activated by user.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not supported out of the box..

But, you can probably use the fine manual from WinCC 7.5(WinCC V7.5 WinCC: Configurations and Communication), page 418, chapter 6.11.5.4 Software Redundancy, no link i know, but its not allowed...
Google keyword "A5E45519419-AA" and somewhere on "siemens.com"

Creation of the needed tags and scripts, simple engineering.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution: (Not nice but maybe helpful in your case) is to use the prefix mechanism. Each HMI variable can be defined with a prefix (usually for dynamic screens when multiple object need to be referenced like a motor). Unfortunately, there is no option (script function) to switch a PLC connection during runtime in any kind of WinCC based SCADAs or HMIs.

Comment: The "HMI" in this case is a SCADA, and change in run is indeed possible via scripts and taggs.

Comment: The possible script functions differ from WinCC v7.x and TIA V17, but anyway I don't know the correct function to be used to change a dynamic IP yet, can you share the link where that function is described (for my own interest)?

Comment: Chapter: 6.11.5.4 Software Redundancy
Link: https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/se/en/view/109792611